# window.history.pushState() data, how and when they are retrieved?

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.history.pushState([data], 'Title', '/url');
```

When I set up data in here, how can I use them and what kind of data this is meant for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `data` object is meant to store structured data of your choosing associated with the history item, so that when the state is revisited, the application has some data available associated with it. Maybe you can save the location of the page that the user was previously viewing, or some form options they had entered but never submitted.

Browsers will call the `popstate()` method when a back button is fired, which will pop the most recent state pushed to the stack. Developers should add an event listener to the `window` object for custom handling of the popstate event (such as using the data associated with the state).

```
// Below function will get fired for every app-wide popstate
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  // Can access state data using event.state.data
});
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, but page does load again from url when I hit back button, can I just load previous content in some changing container with javascript?

Comment: @YuriNko It would have to persist between page loads, which is why pushState is intended to be used here. However, you can also try sessionStorage/localStorage which will save user information until they close the browser.

Comment: Thank you, I already know about thos... I take this approach to just load JSONs from server, instead of whole html every time... Also no reloading of other content is usefull too.

Answer (score 0):

This is like a unqiue identifier to the state that is being pushed. When the time comes when you want to replaceState for that particular state, it will be helpful.

Example:

Store the state:
`var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");`

You could do this to replace the state:
`history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", "bar2.html");`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: Dude, I don't need no replace, I need to call that data, but problem is solved.

Comment: Still, this is interesting but confusing for me what 'data' is actually for.

Comment: I've always found it strange that the main purpose history.pushState is used for, is to update the url but it's named after this extra state parameter which seems to have little use as if state isn't serialised in the url then you can't reproduce the app state when the page is refreshed or shared.